# Close position Binance Futures with ccxt

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

I'm trying to close a position on Binance Futures using ccxt ccxt-1.39.93, Python 3.

```
# fetch position
position = binance.fetch_balance()['info']['positions']
pos = [p for p in position if p['symbol'] == "ETHUSDT"][0]

ticker = get_binance_futures(fetch_only=True)

close_position = binance.create_order(symbol=symbol, type="TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET", side="buy", amount=pos['positionAmt'], price=ticker , params={"closePosition": True, "stopPrice": ticker})
```

I want to close current position. But got this error:

```
ccxt.base.errors.ExchangeError: binance {"code":-2021,"msg":"Order would immediately trigger."}
```

Is there a simple way to close current position at market or spot price for a given symbol ?

Comment: Did you [google the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Order+would+immediately+trigger&oq=Order+would+immediately+trigger)? Do any of these links help solve the problem?

Comment: Yes already tryed. Can't get a working exemple.

Comment: It sounds like your order is formed incorrectly. I suggest you either change the `type` or research what a "take profit" order is.

Answer (score 13):

After somme struggles I finally found a solution.

```
close_position = binance.create_order(symbol=symbol, type="MARKET", side="buy", amount=pos['positionAmt'], params={"reduceOnly": True})
```

Using reduceOnly params did the trick.
No need to setup a price as it is MARKET.

Comment: with this solution u can get error {"code":-4164,"msg":"Order\'s notional must be no smaller than 5 (unless you choose reduce only)."}